# Bootstrap sr-only equivalent in Angular Material

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, accessibility

I've recently began learning and building Angular apps in Angular Material design instead of Twitter Bootstrap. Quick question, is there an equivalent element to the Bootstrap sr-only tag in Angular Material design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `cdk-visually-hidden` class?

See "[Hiding elements, while keeping them available for screen readers](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#hiding-elements-while-keeping-them-available-for-screen-readers)"